# Power spectral density of the system output

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

1. $w(t)$ and $z(t)$: two stationary random processes
2. $z(t) = Pw(t)$.
3. $P$: a stable, LTI system.

How to show:
**$$ S_z(jw) = P(jw)S_w(jw)P(jw)^*$$**

1. $S_z(jw)$ is the power spectral density of $z(t)$
2. $P(jw)$ is the power spectral density of the system.

I remember there is a similar formula for the covariance:  $Cov(z) = PCov(w)P^T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of the fact that 
$$R_z(t)=p(t)*R_w(t)*p^T(-t)$$
where $*$ denote convolution, $R_z(t), R_w(t)$ are the auto-correlation functions of $z,w$ and $p(t)$ is the impulse system response (with Fourier transform $P(j\omega)$).

**Detailed derivation:** since $z,w$ are stationary
$$R_z(t)=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{z(\tau+t)z^T(\tau)d\tau}\\=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(\tau+t-x)w(x)dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w^T(y)p^T(\tau-y)dyd\tau}\\= \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)w(\tau+t-x)dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w^T(\tau-y)p^T(y)dyd\tau}\\=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\left[\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^Tw(\tau+t-x)w^T(\tau-y)d\tau\right]p^T(y)dxdy\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)R_w(t-x+y)p^T(y)dxdy\\
=p(t)*R_{w}(t)*p^T(-t)$$ 
Taking now the Fourier transform we obtain
$$S_z(j\omega)=P(j\omega)S_w(j\omega)P^*(j\omega)$$

Comment: Do we need Fubini somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Supplements to CTNT's answer:

$R_z (t) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} E\{z^T(\tau) z(\tau+t)\} d\tau $ or $R_z(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E\{z^T(\tau) z(\tau+t)\} d\tau$ could be thought as **autocorrelation function** of $z$ sometimes (slightly an abuse of notation, maybe due to historical reasons?); however, for standard notations, in signal processing, **autocorrelation function** of $z$ is usually defined as $E(z^T(\tau) z(t + \tau))$ (normalized additionally in statistics).

Note that, it is not necessary to require $z(t), w(t)$ to be stationary, so that the equation holds. The only difference is the notation, e.g.
$$R_{z(\tau)} (t) := \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} E\{z^T(\tau) z(\tau+t)\} d\tau,$$
which requires integrability and existence of limit,
we still have 
$$R_{z(\tau)}(t) = h(t) * R_{w(\tau)}(t) * h^T(-t)$$

This is just the property of LTI systems.
Even in more general cases,
$$R_z(t_1, t_2) := E\{ z^T(t_1) z(t_2)\},$$
and if defining the notation of convolution for three terms as (the same as we used before; for simplicity $\int \triangleq \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$)
$$g(x)*h(x,y)*k(y) := \int (g(x)*h(x, y-r) ) k(r) dr = g(x) * \left(\int h(x,y-r)k(r)dr\right) = \int g(s)\left(\int h(x-s,y-r)k(r)dr\right) ds = \int \int g(s) h(x-s, y-r) k(r) ds dr,$$
(apparently, $g(x)*h(x,y)*k(y) = \int g(s)(h(x-s, y)*k(y)) ds$)
we have
$$R_z(t_1,t_2) = h(t_1)*R_w(t_1,t_2)*h^T(t_2).$$
Unfortunately, we don't have corresponding in frequency domain. Actually we could derive the form, while without clear physical meaning:
$$S_z(f_1,f_2) = H(f_1) S_w(f_1,f_2) H^T(f_2).$$